# how to get before 1 day data from array in php

Tags: php

I want to get before 1 day data from my array .......last value of my array is base ......so how i get before 1 day data from my array on basis of last value

in my array data will be

```
    [1901] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.0107
        [H] => 0.0107
        [L] => 0.010633
        [C] => 0.01064211
        [V] => 3018.65504806
        [T] => 2017-10-12T20:00:00
        [BV] => 32.24689131
    )

[1902] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.01064211
        [H] => 0.01068489
        [L] => 0.01063301
        [C] => 0.01066111
        [V] => 2405.55511401
        [T] => 2017-10-12T20:30:00
        [BV] => 25.6621846
    )

[1903] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.01066111
        [H] => 0.01068999
        [L] => 0.01059881
        [C] => 0.01065053
        [V] => 2204.80426478
        [T] => 2017-10-12T21:00:00
        [BV] => 23.49363269
    )

[1904] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.01064111
        [H] => 0.01064111
        [L] => 0.010579
        [C] => 0.010581
        [V] => 5477.34718515
        [T] => 2017-10-12T21:30:00
        [BV] => 58.14801298
    )

[1905] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.01060992
        [H] => 0.01061999
        [L] => 0.01055925
        [C] => 0.01055925
        [V] => 1295.68313273
        [T] => 2017-10-12T22:00:00
        [BV] => 13.71553431
    )

[1906] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.01055379
        [H] => 0.01075
        [L] => 0.01055379
        [C] => 0.01063901
        [V] => 4028.03243397
        [T] => 2017-10-12T22:30:00
        [BV] => 42.91348706
    )

[1907] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.0106396
        [H] => 0.01086255
        [L] => 0.01062403
        [C] => 0.01086254
        [V] => 5970.34358887
        [T] => 2017-10-12T23:00:00
        [BV] => 64.443243
    )

[1908] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.01085198
        [H] => 0.01100069
        [L] => 0.0108152
        [C] => 0.011
        [V] => 8098.45644072
        [T] => 2017-10-12T23:30:00
        [BV] => 88.32484248
    )

[1909] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.011
        [H] => 0.01108273
        [L] => 0.01079463
        [C] => 0.01097
        [V] => 9552.72246121
        [T] => 2017-10-13T00:00:00
        [BV] => 104.53520674
    )

[1910] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.01097
        [H] => 0.01099792
        [L] => 0.01068543
        [C] => 0.01070002
        [V] => 6717.53764236
        [T] => 2017-10-13T00:30:00
        [BV] => 72.71144062
    )

[1911] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.01070002
        [H] => 0.01084719
        [L] => 0.01067137
        [C] => 0.01077005
        [V] => 3795.38947434
        [T] => 2017-10-13T01:00:00
        [BV] => 40.8931196
    )

[1912] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.01082149
        [H] => 0.01096
        [L] => 0.01077005
        [C] => 0.01089
        [V] => 7928.74130914
        [T] => 2017-10-13T01:30:00
        [BV] => 86.28752227
    )

[1913] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.01089869
        [H] => 0.0109
        [L] => 0.01054
        [C] => 0.01056426
        [V] => 6724.34568968
        [T] => 2017-10-13T02:00:00
        [BV] => 71.98063356
    )

[1914] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.01056672
        [H] => 0.01057
        [L] => 0.00993751
        [C] => 0.01019941
        [V] => 11290.1350477
        [T] => 2017-10-13T02:30:00
        [BV] => 115.27891267
    )

[1915] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.0102203
        [H] => 0.0104
        [L] => 0.0100707
        [C] => 0.010122
        [V] => 7113.91285039
        [T] => 2017-10-13T03:00:00
        [BV] => 72.44417974
    )

[1916] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.010122
        [H] => 0.01024499
        [L] => 0.01
        [C] => 0.01005709
        [V] => 4658.85947034
        [T] => 2017-10-13T03:30:00
        [BV] => 47.03048392
    )

[1917] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.0100098
        [H] => 0.0100777
        [L] => 0.00993305
        [C] => 0.009935
        [V] => 3072.15120211
        [T] => 2017-10-13T04:00:00
        [BV] => 30.70267092
    )

[1918] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.0099549
        [H] => 0.01002697
        [L] => 0.00989463
        [C] => 0.00994699
        [V] => 6147.17825038
        [T] => 2017-10-13T04:30:00
        [BV] => 60.98741912
    )

[1919] => Array
    (
        [O] => 0.00994167
        [H] => 0.009971
        [L] => 0.00981
        [C] => 0.009871
        [V] => 1369.64657292
        [T] => 2017-10-13T05:00:00
        [BV] => 13.524158
    )
```

in my array last value is  "T" = 2017-10-13T05:00:00

but i want to get before 1 day data
like last value is 2017-10-13T05:00:00   i want to get data from 2017-10-12T05:00:00 to 2017-10-13T05:00:00  how can i do it and my main array name is result.....!!

i tried this code

```
<?php
$url2 = 'https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/pub/market/GetTicks?marketName=BTC-LTC&tickInterval=thirtyMin';
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL,$url2);
$result2=curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);
$a2 = json_decode($result2, true);
$b2 =  $a2['result'];

for($i=0; $i<count($b2);$i++){
$c = $b2[$i];
$bi1 = $c['H'];
$bi2 = $c['L'];
$bi3 = $c['O'];
$bi4 = $c['C'];
$bi5 = $c['T'];

//echo $bi5;
//echo "<br>";

//echo $stop_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($bi5. ' -1 day'));
//echo "<br>";

echo $stop_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($bi5. ' -30 min'));
echo "<br>";


}



?>
```

Comment: you can do something like `where date <= NOW() and date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: @Arav What did you tried so far?

Comment: so you are hitting url through curl. did you send date also to fetch specific record or just hiting the given url

Comment: @Arav  i asked a question to you

Comment: code is given in my question in last